# FFMPEG - Scroll filter on filter_complex applies on under layer

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

I apply filter_complex to put objects on coordinates using overlay. Sometime, I need to use the scroll filter.

Here is the code

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -i /tmp/2SN92agDIG.png -i /tmp/TogmpB9etD.png -i /tmp/lxiQXCxhaZ-1.png -filter_complex "color=size=312x312:c=0xffffff,loop=-1[color];\
[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,scale=480x320,rotate=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0),format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=1[0];\
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,scale=298x301,rotate=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0),format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.8[1];\
[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,scale=288x614,rotate=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0),format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=1[2];\
[color][0]overlay=x=-76.18:y=-4[-1+0];\
[-1+0][1]overlay=x=8.043499999999995:y=5.044000000000011[0+1];\
[0+1][2]overlay=x=8.021000000000015:y=0,scroll=vertical=0.02857142857142857" -map 0:a? -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy -t 35 -y
```

It works great but when this filter is applied on an object which is on top of other objects (Ex. third object in the filter complex chain), the scroll is applied to all under layer.

Do you have an idea how can I "isolate" the scroll to be applies only on one object ?

Thanks.

Comment: The scroll should be applied within the `[2:v]` filtering.

Comment: How can I connect the output of the filter scroll to my filter_complex ? Thanks

Comment: Shift the scroll to after the `colorchannelmixer` for `2:v`

Comment: I tried this `[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,scale=288x614,rotate=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0),format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=1,scroll=vertical=0.02857142857142857[2];` But i got `Filter scroll has an unconnected output`

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: Here it is : https://pastebin.com/GEAwbsXH  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You removed the final overlay. Why?

Comment: Because if I let it, there is no movement

Comment: I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: Did you find a way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image to be scrolled has to be looped first and then scrolled.

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -i /tmp/2SN92agDIG.png -i /tmp/TogmpB9etD.png -i /tmp/lxiQXCxhaZ-1.png -filter_complex "color=size=312x312:c=0xffffff[color];\
[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,scale=480x320,rotate=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0),format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=1[0v];\
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,scale=298x301,rotate=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0),format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.8[1v];\
[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,scale=288x614,rotate=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0),format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=1,loop=1:1,scroll=vertical=0.02857142857142857[2v];\
[color][0v]overlay=x=-76.18:y=-4[-1+0];\
[-1+0][1v]overlay=x=8.043499999999995:y=5.044000000000011[0+1];\
[0+1][2v]overlay=x=8.021000000000015:y=0" -c:v h264_nvenc -t 35 -y out.mp4
```

(there are quite a few unnecessary or inert elements in this command, but I haven't removed them, such as the rotate filters which don't perform any rotation)

Comment: Thanks for you help, I tried with your command and the result is I only have a little movement at the beginning (less than a second) but it's fixed then

Comment: I added like loop=-1:75:0 and it's working like a charm :) Thanks for your help